# Finance manager

Tags: java, performance, file-system, finance, javafx

Somewhat experienced with JavaFX, but this is my first potentially large JavaFX project that I recently started and wanted some feedback on anything that could be done better or more efficiently thus far, before continuing.

Note: I am aware that there are a few functions not in use, I'm just leaving them in for future use.

`main` does nothing really special.

```
package Java.Application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Resources/MainWindow.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Finance Manager");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1200, 700));
        //primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The `MainController`, on run the application will determine which file in a directory was most recently used, the files information is then parsed and loaded into the UI. The directory is filled with .fmd files, which is just a custom little file format I created, which stands for finance manager data. This is the first time I've created a file format for an application and would especially enjoy thoughts on this part of the application. I will include the inside of a .fmd file at the end.

Specific thought: the `setLabels()` method's readability is just awful, but maybe that is just me.

```
package Java.Controllers;

import Java.Application.*;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class MainController implements Initializable{
    public Label profileName, yearlyIncome, monthlyIncome, weeklyIncome, dailyIncome,
            yearlyAfterExpenses, monthlyAfterExpenses, weeklyAfterExpenses, dailyAfterExpenses;
    public TableColumn<Statement, String> colExpense, colYearly, colMonthly, colWeekly, colDaily, colNotes;
    public TableView<Statement> expenseTable;

    private String PATH = "Profiles/"; // TODO: Allow profile path to be changed to a different default.

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resource){
        setTableCellValues(); // Sets table columns with correct properties.
        if(Directory.getSize(PATH) > 0){
            try {
                loadFile(FileTools.getMostRecentFile(PATH));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("File Failed To Load.");
            } catch (ParseException ex){
                System.err.println("Date Could'nt Be Parsed.");
            }
        }
    }

    private void setTableCellValues() {
        colExpense.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());
        colYearly.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().yearlyProperty());
        colMonthly.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().monthlyProperty());
        colWeekly.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().weeklyProperty());
        colDaily.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().dailyProperty());
        colNotes.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().noteProperty());
    }

    private void loadFile(File file){
        try{
            FmdParser parser = new FmdParser(file);
            List<Statement> incomeStatements = parser.getAll("income");
            List<Statement> expenseStatements = parser.getAll("expense");

            setLabels(file, incomeStatements, expenseStatements); // Sets labels appropriately.
            expenseTable.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(expenseStatements));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("File Failed To Load.");
        }
    }

    private void setLabels(File file, List<Statement> incomes, List<Statement> expenses){
        double yearly = StatementTools.getYearlySummation(incomes);
        double monthly = StatementTools.getMonthlySummation(incomes);
        double weekly = StatementTools.getWeeklySummation(incomes);
        double daily = StatementTools.getDailySummation(incomes);

        profileName.setText("Profile Name: " + FileTools.getFileName(file));
        yearlyIncome.setText(String.format("Yearly Income: $%.2f", yearly));
        monthlyIncome.setText(String.format("Monthly Income: $%.2f", monthly));
        weeklyIncome.setText(String.format("Weekly Income: $%.2f", weekly));
        dailyIncome.setText(String.format("Daily Income: $%.2f", daily));

        yearlyAfterExpenses.setText(String.format("After Expenses: $%.2f", yearly - StatementTools.getYearlySummation(expenses)));
        monthlyAfterExpenses.setText(String.format("After Expenses: $%.2f", monthly - StatementTools.getMonthlySummation(expenses)));
        weeklyAfterExpenses.setText(String.format("After Expenses: $%.2f", weekly - StatementTools.getWeeklySummation(expenses)));
        dailyAfterExpenses.setText(String.format("After Expenses: $%.2f", daily - StatementTools.getDailySummation(expenses)));
    }
}
```

`FmdParser` is used to parse the .fmd files information:

```
package Java.Application;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created on 8/4/2016.
 *
 */
public class FmdParser{
    File fmdFile;

    public FmdParser(File file){
        if(FileTools.getFileExtension(file).equals("fmd")){
            fmdFile = file;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported File Format");
        }
    }

    public List<Statement> getAll(String type) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fmdFile));
        List<Statement> statements = new ArrayList<>();

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] parsed = line.split(":");
            if(parsed[0].equals(type)){
                String[] attributes = parsed[1].split(",");
                statements.add(new Statement(
                        attributes[0],
                        Double.valueOf(attributes[1]),
                        Double.valueOf(attributes[2]),
                        Double.valueOf(attributes[3]),
                        Double.valueOf(attributes[4]),
                        attributes[5]));
            }
        }
        return statements;
    }
}
```

The `Statement` class groups all of the information that starts with `expense:` or `income:` in the .fmd file. The information in the class can then be calculated, or loaded into a TableView if need be.

```
package Java.Application;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

/**
 * Created on 8/4/2016.
 *
 */
public class Statement {
    double yearly, monthly, weekly, daily;
    private StringProperty nameProperty, yearlyProperty, monthlyProperty, weeklyProperty, dailyProperty, noteProperty;

    public Statement(String name, double yearly, double monthly, double weekly, double daily, String note){
        // Double variables, used in mathematical purposes.
        this.yearly = yearly;
        this.monthly = monthly;
        this.weekly = weekly;
        this.daily = daily;

        // StringProperty variables, used for storing information in javafx view tables.
        this.nameProperty = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.yearlyProperty = new SimpleStringProperty(String.valueOf(yearly));
        this.monthlyProperty = new SimpleStringProperty(String.valueOf(monthly));
        this.weeklyProperty = new SimpleStringProperty(String.valueOf(weekly));
        this.dailyProperty = new SimpleStringProperty(String.valueOf(daily));
        this.noteProperty = new SimpleStringProperty(note);
    }

    /**
     * Used to return the specified variable of the Statement instance.
     *
     */
    public String getName() {
        return nameProperty.get();
    }

    public double getYearly() {
        return yearly;
    }

    public double getMonthly() {
        return monthly;
    }

    public double getWeekly() {
        return weekly;
    }

    public double getDaily() {
        return daily;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return noteProperty.get();
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return nameProperty;
    }

    public StringProperty yearlyProperty() {
        return yearlyProperty;
    }

    public StringProperty monthlyProperty() {
        return monthlyProperty;
    }

    public StringProperty weeklyProperty() {
        return weeklyProperty;
    }

    public StringProperty dailyProperty() {
        return dailyProperty;
    }

    public StringProperty noteProperty() {
        return noteProperty;
    }
}
```

`StatementTools` is a class containing static methods that are used strictly for calculating statement information.

Specific thought: it's a shame to have so many methods doing pretty much the exact same thing, but I couldn't think of a way to compress the four down into one efficiently.

```
package Java.Application;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 * Created on 8/5/2016.
 *
 */
public class StatementTools {

    public static double getDailySummation(List<Statement> statements) {
        return statements.stream().collect(Collectors.summingDouble(Statement::getDaily));
    }

    public static double getMonthlySummation(List<Statement> statements) {
        return statements.stream().collect(Collectors.summingDouble(Statement::getMonthly));
    }

    public static double getWeeklySummation(List<Statement> statements) {
        return statements.stream().collect(Collectors.summingDouble(Statement::getWeekly));
    }

    public static double getYearlySummation(List<Statement> statements) {
        return statements.stream().collect(Collectors.summingDouble(Statement::getYearly));
    }

}
```

`FileTools` is a class used for extracting data from files:

```
package Java.Application;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created on 8/4/2016.
 */
public class FileTools {
    public static List<String> getFileContents(File file) throws IOException {
        return Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), Charset.forName("utf-8"));
    }

    // Only compatible with windows files.
    public static String getFileExtension(File file){
        String fileName = file.getName();
        return fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    }

    public static String getFileName(File file){
        String fileName = file.getName();
        return fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
    }

    public static File getMostRecentFile(String path) throws IOException, ParseException {
        File[] files = Directory.getFiles(path);

        switch(files.length){
            case 0 : return null;
            case 1 : return files[0];
        }

        File mostRecentFile = files[0];
        Date mostRecentDate = new Date(mostRecentFile.lastModified());
        for(int i = 1; i < files.length; i++){
            Date possibleMostRecentDate = new Date(files[i].lastModified());

            if(mostRecentDate.before(possibleMostRecentDate)){
                mostRecentFile = files[i];
                mostRecentDate = new Date(mostRecentFile.lastModified());
            }
        }
        return mostRecentFile;
    }

    public static String readLine(String path, int line) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

        // Reads line until wanted line number is reached.
        String l = reader.readLine();
        for(int i = 1; i <= line; i++){
            l = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
        return l;
    }

}
```

`Directory` is a small class containing methods for working with directories:

```
package Java.Application;

import java.io.File;

/**
 * Created on 8/4/2016.
 */
public class Directory {

    public static int getSize(String path){
        return new File(path).listFiles().length;
    }

    public static File[] getFiles(String path){
        return new File(path).listFiles();
    }
}
```

An example of the inside of a .fmd file:

File name: Bob Smith.fmd

> ```
> income:Programming,100000,8333.33,1851.85,273.97,None
> income:Holidays,1000,83.33,19.8,2.8,None
> expense:Cell Phone,1200,100,23.81,3.40,None
> expense:Internet,1800,150,35.71,5.10,None
> ```

I didn't post the fxml file as I think I've posted more than enough already, but if you want to see it, just comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have no experience with JavaFX, so I'll focus on other points. Feel free to ask for more details regarding specific advice if needed.

[**Naming Conventions**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)

Package names should be lowercase and not start with "java".

**Consistency**

Sometimes you have a whitespace between your braces ("`) {`"), sometimes you don't ("`){`"). This itself is really a minor issue, but makes me think that you currently do not auto-format your code. As this generally makes life easier I suggest to let your IDE format your code for you.

Example from your code:

```
try {
    loadFile(FileTools.getMostRecentFile(PATH));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println("File Failed To Load.");
} catch (ParseException ex){
    System.err.println("Date Could'nt Be Parsed.");
}
```

**Exception Handling**

Use a logger instead of `System.err` and also include the exception itself in the logging output. Both makes it a lot easier to maintain your application and find (potential) issues without having to debug everything each time.

Have a look at the [`java.util.logging`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) package.

**Variable Declarations**

[Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141270.html) suggest to have one declaration per line, i.e.:

```
public Label profileName;
public Label yearlyIncome;
public Label monthlyIncome;
```

Instead of

```
public Label profileName, yearlyIncome, monthlyIncome;
```

**Resource Handling**

I haven't really verified it, but at first glance it looks like you might have a few potential resource leaks.

Have a look at [the `try-with-resources` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

**Charsets**

Instead of using `Charset.forName("utf-8")` you can use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`since Java 7.

**Directory Listing**

In certain cases `new File().listFiles()` may return `null` (cf. [the corresponding javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles--)), so you may run into `NullPointerException`s with your `Directory` class.

Have a look at Java 7's new [`java.nio.file`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) package for more advanced and modern methods.

**Calculations**

When writing anything that requires correct calculations (e.g. a finance manager), [do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179427/how-to-resolve-a-java-rounding-double-issue) [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906169/weird-java-behavior-how-come-adding-doubles-with-exactly-two-decimal-places-res?noredirect=1&lq=1) [use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667324/unpredictable-double) [`double`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867445/double-my-money-my-framework-uses-doubles-for-monetary-amounts?noredirect=1&lq=1). There are basically two ways to do this right:

- Store everything as the smallest unit (i.e. only cents) and use `long`
- Use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)